# How do I unsubscribe to the multiplayer quick search beta?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I accidently clicked yes on the popup and now I'm stuck using this slow quick play search and I don't know how to turn it off. The new search takes exponentially more time than the old one. I've been waiting 20 minutes just to get into a game. How do I unsubscribe to the multiplayer quick search beta?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way I have found is to quit the game and relaunch it. After you do that, it will ask you again whether you want to participate in the beta when you choose quick search.

Answer (score 0):

Open the console and type `tf_quickplay_beta_preference 0`

Answer (score -1):

Just restart i think.

Or type tf_quickplay_beta_preference 0 in the console

Comment: Why is this answer being downvoted? I know both have already been suggested, but he might not have noticed.